# Use Javascript to alter a css style sheet if the user is logged in

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I've got a Wordpress website which uses the same colour a lot throughout the site.

I want this colour to change if the user is logged in.

My solutions so far:

- I can write a conditional PHP statement so a secondary stylesheet is enqueued if the user is logged in
- I can add another body class if the user is logged in, and then target certain classes where this is present.

Both seem inelegant and require writing loads of CSS.

Any thoughts on alternative approaches? It feels like Javascript might be a better option here?

Comment: IMO "loads of CSS" is in all cases more elegant than writing js to style color, which is meant to be styled with css

Comment: No, JavaScript isn’t a better option, and both of your solutions so far are very elegant. Lots of CSS is just how color schemes work, no way around it =) You can use a CSS preprocessor like Sass to produce colors used in CSS from certain configurable base colors, but that only goes so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the solutions you presented is better than using Javascript to set the color of the page. By using JS to change the color you are effectively moving styling away from the CSS/Stylesheet layer (where it belongs) and into the control layer.

Loading a different stylesheet if the user is logged in is definitely not inelegant, it is a perfectly acceptable solution. It is good practice to hold different color schemes in your CSS and use them conditionally.

Likewise adding an additional tag is not a bad solution either, though does complicate your CSS rule set a bit.

Comment: Thanks for this Alien. I'll go for this solution

Answer (score 1):

You can have two classes for the two colors, and output the class with PHP.

All you will need in your CSS is two classes specifying the two colors:

```
.color-anonymous {
    background-color:  #888;
}

.color-logged-in {
    background-color: #909;
}
```

In your PHP file add a variable `$color` which shall hold the value of the CSS color class based on whether the user is logged in or not, and use it to output the correct class in your HTML.

```
<?php
    $color = '';
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $color = 'color-logged-in';
    } else {
        $color = 'color-anonymous';
}

//elsewhere
<div class="some-other-class <?= $color ?>">Hello</div>
```

?>

Comment: Hi Penny, This a is a nice idea. Unfortunately, because i'm targeting HTML classes which are written as part of Wordpress / WooCommerce / other 3rd party plugins I've not got the ability to output the class within my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can dynamically insert the css style sheet using javascript:

```
  <script>
      if(<?php$_SESSION['logedIN']?>=="yes"){
           var filename="loged.css";
      }else{
          var filename="notloged.css";
        }
      var head = document.head;
      var link = document.createElement('link')
      link.setAttribute(type ,'text/css');
      link.setAttribute(rel,'stylesheet');
      link.setAttribute(href, fileName);
      head.appendChild(link);

</script>
```

Comment: It would make more sense to just conditionally add the style sheet using only PHP, why use JS to load it? More overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It's need some understanding for jQ and WordPress:

In function.php:

```
function your_theme_localize(){
       $login_in = is_user_logged_in(); // return true or false
       wp_localize_script( 'your-js-file', 'variable-for-js', $login_in );
       //your-js-file is a handler for Your .js file  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_theme_localize' );
```

and then in "your-js-file.js":

```
function some_function(){
    var is_logged_in = variable-for-js;
}
```